# Error 500 while Sharing via Google plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, google-plus

We are developing an application which uses google plus share's sdk 1.7.1 .It was working fine until we changed the bundle-id in console of google Developers.So we create a new client-id,the it started giving an error 500 in safari after loging in succesfully just before redirecting to the app.we have checked the schema which is correct.This issue does not occurs every time.

[image]

We have also set the Url Types both identifier and schema correctly.

Comment: I also have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm your steps:

1. Register iOS app in developer console
2. Change app bundle ID
3. Sharing breaks (error 500)
4. You change the bundle identifier associated with the client id shipping in your app
5. Sharing is still broken.

A few things that could break this:

- Updating the bundle identifier sometimes causes issues, you might want to register an additional client all together and use this client ID.
- Ensure that you have updated the Client ID in your sample to match any changes in the client ID that could have occurred in the console.